# What is the size of the largest subset with a pairwise hamming distance of 3

Tags: combinatorics, binary, gray-code

Consider all binary strings of length $n$. Is there any known bounds on the size of the maximum subset such that the pairwise hamming distance between any two elements is at least 3.

Comment: Each element is surrounded by $n$ others that differ by one bit, and the neighbourhoods don't intersect, so one bound is $2^n/(n+1)$

Comment: Here is a table of the best known bounds for small $n$: https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/codes/binary-1.html (thanks to @RobertIsrael for correcting my last comment).

Comment: See also [OEIS sequence A005864](https://oeis.org/A005864) and references there.

Comment: @Empy2 What is the guarantee that the neighbourhoods don't intersect? The bound that you mentioned is close to i want for a problem i am working on. I need $n$ distinct elements in each neighbourhood, for a set of size atmost $2^{n}/n$, whose neighbourhoods cover the entire $2^{n}$ strings. But I am having trouble proving that such a partition exist.

Comment: If they intersect then the two points are two bits apart.

Comment: @Empy2 I should have made it clear, what i want is the guarantee that such a subset exists for every $n$. Can we always pick $2^{n}/(n+1)$ elements, whose neighbourhoods don't intersect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** I found a much better solution, so I have overhauled this answer.

You already have the upper bound $$A_2(n,3)\le \frac{2^{n}}{n+1}.$$ which is just the sphere bound. For a lower bound, you can use the [Hamming code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code)  of length $n$, which proves
$$
A_2(n,3)\ge 2^{n-\lfloor \log_2(n)\rfloor-1}\ge \frac{2^{n-2}}{n}
$$
Therefore, this is within a factor of $4$ of the optimal code.

In general, finding the optimal code is an open problem. There is a [table of best known bounds for binary codes maintained here](https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Eaeb/codes/binary-1.html).